# Real examples of complex PID regulators

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control, nonlinear-control

I am currently developing the C library for easy implementation of PID controllers. Can you give some examples of complex PID controllers from real life? I don't mean a simple DC motor with a speed regulator or something like that, but a tricky one that you may have been dealing with.

Comment: Quadcopter. Two-wheel balancing robot.

Comment: Actuators with rate limits that are less than control output. For instance, the slew rate of a cruise ship stabilizer fin.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of "tricky" control situations which require completely different modifications to the PID algorithm. Here are a few:

Systems where the outputs go dead intermittently resulting in integral windup. Some PID implementations can handle this more gracefully than others. This is a very common problem, but has decent solutions with pros and cons.

Systems which require a very fast response, such that filtering the inputs becomes a compromise. Look at the the filtering algorithms in betaflite (a drone firmware), they're very complicated.

Cascaded systems, where you don't control the process variable directly. For example you control the temperature of a fluid with a PID loop, and that fluid heats and cools the process (using another loop to set the temperature). If you try to control this with one loop it will have terrible stability and overshooting due to the lag and thermal mass of the system.

Laggy systems, where changes in the process variable don't show up at the input for several minutes, or more commonly, the input tracks but always lags behind the real process variable. This very common, and unfortunately very difficult to control with PID. There are ways where you for example use a predictive algorithm to estimate the "real" process value, but that's a whole can of worms when it comes to stability.

My recommendation when testing your library is to create and try to control some systems like this. You can simulate most of them fairly easily in software.